# Construction of object with non-default constructor inside C++ class

Tags: c++, constructor, oop

Iam new to C++ and below mentioned is the summary of the problem.  Bar's constructor needs to explicitly call foo's constructor and the argument to foo's constructor has to be an object to baz, which has a default constructor. Iam not allowed to use new operator(dynamic allocation) to achieve this. I tried the below code, but C++ compiler gives me compilation errors (listed below). Can somebody please explain me what's going wrong in this code? Any help is really appreciated.

```
//Constructor.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    // two of two, yay!

class baz {
public:
baz() { };
};

class Foo {
public:
Foo(baz y) { }
};

class Bar  {
public:
Foo x;
baz y;
Bar() : Foo(y) { };
};

int main() {
Bar b;
}

Syntax Error on compiling.
--------------------------
constructor.cpp: In constructor `Bar::Bar()':
constructor.cpp:19: error: type `Foo' is not a direct base of `Bar' 
constructor.cpp:19: error: no matching function for call to `Foo::Foo()'
constructor.cpp:9: note: candidates are: Foo::Foo(const Foo&)
constructor.cpp:11: note:                 Foo::Foo(baz)
```

Comment: There's a missing `;` after the first class.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Added semicolon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Bar() : Foo(y) { };
```

What are you doing here? `Foo` is not a member of `Bar`. It's a type. `x` is a member of type `Foo`.

But even if you write `x(y)`, there is a problem in the order of initialization. As `x` is depending on `y`, so `y` must be initialized before `x`. So declare `y` before `x` to ensure the correct initialization!

I would suggest this change:

```
class Bar  
{
   public:
      baz y;
      Foo x; //NOTE : x declared after y, as x is depending on y!
      Bar() : x(y) {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`Bar` isn't derived from `Foo`, it has a member called `x` of type `Foo` so `x` must appear in the *mem-initializer-list*.

```
Bar : x(y) {}
```

For this to be valid, though, the declaration of `y` must appear before the declaration of `x` in the definition of `class Bar` as the order of initialization of members of a class always occurs in the order in which the member declarations appear in the definition of the class and, if you are initializing `x` from `y` you will want `y` to be initialized before `x`.

Also, note you are missing a semicolon after the definition of `class baz`.