# Accessing a method of a member object in C++

Tags: c++, class, object, static-methods

I am trying to access a method of an object (`myEOS.calc(...)`) from a method of an object (`myPlanet`) of another class containing an instance of the first class (`static EOS myEOS`):

```
// class in class

class EOS {
  public:
    static float Y;
    float calc(float);
};
float EOS::calc(float x){
  return x;                      // some complicated calculation
}

class Planet {
  public:
    static EOS myEOS;            // want only one instance; cf. below
    static void setX(float* X);  // must be static; cf. below
};
void Planet::setX(float* X) {
  *X = myEOS.calc(*X);           // will give an error
}

int main(){
  Planet myPlanet;
}
```

This returns the linking-time error

```
In function `Planet::setX(float*)':
test.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `Planet::myEOS'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Compiling separately, with `-c`, the classes and the main program (with an `#include` in the main file) gives no error; this looks like the key to the solution but I do not see the lock!

Does someone know what the problem is? I hope my intent is clear from what I have, even if there is some fundamental misconception. I thought I somewhat understood classes and reread tutorials but saw no discussion of classes within classes (not nested classes). I was not able to find a similar question on this site (from which I can usually get all the answers I need!) either.

By the way, following [somebody else's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058014/construction-of-object-with-non-default-constructor-inside-c-class), adding explicit constructors (and correctly initialising the EOS in Planet's initialiser list) did not remove the compiler complaint about "undefined reference to `Planet::myEOS'" (this done without the`static` keyword).

Finally, note that `Planet::setX` needs to be static because a pointer to this method must have a "class-less" signature as it is passed to a function that cannot handle methods/classes:

```
 void (*fun_ptr)(float*) = & (Planet::setX);
```

This also forces the object `myEOS` to be static (needs to be accessed from a static function), and anyway the initialisation of `EOS` objects is expensive.

Thanks a lot for anybody's help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Planet {
  public:
    static EOS myEOS;            // want only one instance; cf. below
```

This code says "Compiler: Somewhere *later* will be a *global* `EOS myEOS` for this class.  And the compiler says "ok", and does it's thing, waiting for you to tell it where the global `EOS myEOS` is.
Then the linker comes along to clean up the compiler's mess, and says "I can't find the `myEOS`, where'd you place the `myEOS`?" And displays an error.

You need to add the following lines to a CPP file somewhere:

```
float EOS::Y;
EOS Planet::myEOS;
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer and the explanation, which I however do not quite understand: why would the linker not find the Y anymore? (Of course, your suggestions worked, and I actually had the `float EOS::Y` already, in an other file--sorry!)

Comment: You're right, it was confusing.  I reworded the "little story" to make more sense.  I also switched from `Y` to `myEOS` since that was the linker error.  It couldn't find Y because nobody ever _made_ the `Planet::myEOS`.

Answer (score 2):

Define the static variable.

```
// class in class

class EOS {
  public:
    static float Y;
    float calc(float);
};
float EOS::calc(float x){
  return x;                      // some complicated calculation
}

class Planet {
  public:
    static EOS myEOS;            // want only one instance; cf. below
    static void setX(float* X);  // must be static; cf. below
};
void Planet::setX(float* X) {
  *X = myEOS.calc(*X);           // will give an error
}

// -------------------------
EOS Planet::myEOS;
float Planet::Y /* = <some value> if it makes sense*/;
// -------------------------

int main(){
  Planet myPlanet;
}
```

See 9.4.2 Static Data Members in the standard (98).

Comment: Thanks MD for pointing out. I made the same error that I corrected. :)

Comment: @thekashyap Thanks for your answer and for the reference--this is helpful. Please see comment to MD about `Y`.